# Insert to database date and time

Tags: oracle-apex

I'm trying to insert to database the current date and time, but inserts only date.
Column Data Type: *Date*
Format mask: *YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS*.
PL/SQL Expression `TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS')` or `to_char(sysdate,'YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS')`
Data inserts automatically when form is submitted (I seted column name and data type (date)).
How to insert date and time correctly?

Comment: Best practice is to use a trigger to record a sysdate/systimestamp.

Comment: Thank you. I try it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can actually just insert SYSDATE. sysdate is a Date data type, so is the column. One think though, when you then do a Select on the column, it only shows the date, not the time. Thats just because thats the default display mask for the date. in you do a TO_CHAR in the select, you get the time out as well.

Comment: Thank you. I thought that result from database is same as visible value.